# Sending File(Any type) from node server and receving it in html

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I want to send a file from Node server using get Method and want to receive it on Angular2 client side
Here is my Api for getting a file:

**File Receiver Api Using Node Express**

```
  function getUserFileByEmail(req, res) {
  UserCv.findOne({ emailAddress: req.params.emailAddress }, (err, usercv) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    }
    const filePath = path.join('E:/Work/node-portal/uploads', usercv.file);
    console.log(filePath);//this is printing the exact file name along with extension that i want to receive at cliend end
    usercv.file = filePath;

          res.sendFile(filePath);

  });
}
```

and in client side my code is:

**FileReceiver request using angular2**

```
getfile() {

        return this.http.get(`${this._getfile}/${user.emailAddress}`, options)
            .map(res=> (<Response>res).blob())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

By doing this i am receiving an error that is:
**"The request body isn't either a blob or an array buffer"**
So any one knows what exactly I am doing wrong in my server side or client side file